# LwC Open Source posting information to endpoint

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm collecting information from user entry and would like to POST the information to external RESTful API. I've read a little on the @WIRE service in LwC but not sure how post JSON to that service. To get info --- i used the fetch()  successfully.

Could some point me to any simple code walk through's that explain this --- leveraging LwC outside of Salesforce? I haven't been able to find any simple guidance?

```
 // Button eventhandler --- called onclick
 handleEnroll(event) {
    // Populate object with data from UI/ HTML
    enrollResp.Steps = this.Steps;
    enrollResp.notifyType = this.notifyType;
    enrollResp.device = this.application;
    enrollResp.goal = this.goal;
    enrollResp.fromAcc = this.fromAcc;
    enrollResp.toAcc = this.toAcc;
    enrollResp.notifyAddress = this.notifyAddress;

    // POST to RESTful API 
    // ???
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are saying that you already know how to GET data using fetch() in your JS file? 
If so, making a POST request shouldn't be too hard. 
Basically, you have two options:

- you can use fetch() (like you did) or the newer async/await to make the callout. Make sure your endpoint is whitelisted within SF, using CSP trusted sites. There is a lot of documentation about making a POST request using javascript online, so I'm not going to take you through the steps here.
- the second option would be to create an async Apex class and do the request from there. You can check out the integration modules on Trailhead for that, if you need more information.

It's a matter of preference whether you would like to use Apex or Javascript between the two options. Although in terms of performance, I'd think that doing it directly in the JS file might be slightly better.

Let me know if this helps and if you run into any problems.

Comment: Thanks Sabastiaan --- pointed me in the right direction--- new to LwC :  got a little distracted by the wire service ----- going to use the fetch for the post as not using APEX backend...… thanks :)

Comment: @darthal Cool! No problem :)